# escape special characters from html

Tags: java, html

I am creating a html table.

```
<table class=" table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
   <th>Remarks</th>
</tr></thead>
<tr>
   <td> hello <hi> html </td>
</table>
```

When I run the above code, I get a result like 
"hello html". I need to display full text like `" hello <hi> html "`

Comment: I need to display full text like "hello <hi> html  "

Comment: where do u need to display a full text?

Comment: In table row(inside the <td> tag)

Comment: so remove the hi tag

Answer (score 4):

Use [html entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp):

```
<td>hello &lt;hi&gt; html</td>
```

Comment: actually that message("hello <hi> html") is fetching from database.

Comment: Still you can perform a replace to html entities then

Comment: instead of replacing < as &l, is there any other solution?

Comment: It's not `&l,` it's `&lt;` (I think lt stands fot 'less than').

Comment: If code looks like "<td>LABEL </td>", consider LABEL is a variable and value of this variable is getting from database.How can i replace "<" like &lt.

Comment: The `&lt;` should finish in semicolon. In many ways. You can do it in JavaScript, in java and even in your database when fetchibg the data, there are always methods to perform a replace. But we should see more of your code or have a better idea to know which one would be better in your specific case, even though all of them should work

Comment: @Rahul Escapping text and attributes when formatting in HTML is **mandatory**, in order to avoid malicous HTML code injection, which would produce security issues.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged "Java", I suggest that you use the [`Commons Text`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) library to convert the html caracters to entities.

[`org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils#escapeHtml4`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `script` like this:

```
<script>
function loadPage() {
    document.body.querySelector("td").innerText = unescape(escape(document.body.querySelector("td").innerHTML));
}
</script>
```

and add

`onload="loadPage();"` to `body`.

Comment: Can i create a style class to replace all special characters from <td> tag?

Comment: @Rahul can you elaborate? You can use custom fonts, but I'm not sure whether that's your intention.